# PUTS jumps to beginning of PC?

Tags: assembly, lc3

So I'm pretty new to LC-3 language. Every time I execute a PUTS instruction, the PC goes from my current place (like x3001) straight to x0000 and I am not sure why.

My code looks like this:

LD R0, PROMPT1
PUTS

I am not very knowledgeable on all the trap functions and how they work.

Comment: It should execute the trap that prints the string, which is a simple loop around printing one character of the string at a time.  (1) What LC-3 tooling are you using? (2) What happens if you continue to single step?